# How to compile whole Typescript project to Executable

Tags: node.js, typescript, compilation, executable

I got this typescript project that includes multiple folders and config file that are linked to each other. It’s basically a larger script. What it the best way to compile it to executable?

Main points:

•   Multiple Typescript files linked to each other
•   Node modules

•   Some Typescript files are using FS to read from config files

•   Config files needs to stay accessible so the user can edit them

•   SCV file is the output of the script

All these functionalities need to be working after compilation to executable.
I already tried using Nexe and Verse’s Pkg but I encounter limitations in both cases.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score -1):

in node.js, you can use [pkg](https://github.com/vercel/pkg).

in deno, you can use `deno compile`.

examples:

`deno compile -A --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu test.ts`

`deno compile -A --target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc test.ts`